# Null object reference when using string resources for ListView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Why is it that whenever I try to use a simple array for a `ListView`, I get this error?:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong here as I've tried using different contexts (`base` and `application`) but still no change in solving this issue.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var array = arrayOf(resources.getString(R.string.item_a), 
        resources.getString(R.string.item_b), 
        resources.getString(R.string.item_c), 
        resources.getString(R.string.item_d))

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listview_item, array)

        val listView:ListView = findViewById(R.id.listview_1)
        listView.setAdapter(adapter)
    }

override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
    if (array[position] == resources.getString(R.string.item_a)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hi there! This is a Toast.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: can you consider moving this line   `var array = arrayOf(resources.getString(R.string.item_a), resources.getString(R.string.item_b), resources.getString(R.string.item_c), resources.getString(R.string.item_d), )`  inside the `onCreate()` method

Comment: I did but why does `array` in `if (array[position] == resources.getString(R.string.item_a))` give this error now? `Unresolved reference: array`

Comment: maybe because you have not defined a variable named array in the scope you are refering.

Comment: @mightyWOZ Does this need to be define before `onCreate`?

Comment: you can declare it as a class variable then you will be able to access it in any function.

Comment: @mightyWOZ would I do something like `lateinit var array: Array`?

Answer (score 0):

Two things going on here.

First, if you declare and initialize an array of string resources at the class level of your activity, you will get an error. Your activity isn't "ready" immediately when it is constructed; it needs to have `super.onCreate()` called before you'll be able to access resources.

Second, if you move the entire array inside `onCreate()` then you won't be able to access it from `onItemClick()` (since now it is local to onCreate).

The solution is to use a `lateinit var` so that you can declare your array at the class level but then initialize it inside `onCreate()`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var array: Array<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.array = arrayOf(...)
        // ...
    }

    override fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int) {
        if (array[position] == resources.getString(R.string.item_a)){
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```